# ionic 1 Themeable Browser not opening in android device

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, browser, hybrid-mobile-app

Here my flow...

I added both `ios and android`platform

Installed it `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser`

My example pdf :  http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf

that plugin in github: https://github.com/initialxy/cordova-plugin-themeablebrowser

My `index.html` :

```
 <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Ionic Blank Starter</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content ng-controller="FileOpenerController">

       <button class="button button-icon loginnavbtn" ng-click="openpdf()">pdf open</button>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
```

my `.js`

```
    app.controller('FileOpenerController', function($scope, $ionicPlatform,$themeablebrowser) {

    var options = {
                toolbar: {
                    height: 44,
                    color: '#cdcdcd'
              },
                title: {
                    color: '#003264ff',
                    showPageTitle: true
              },
                closeButton: {
                    image: 'close',
                    imagePressed: 'close_pressed',
                    align: 'left',
                    event: 'closePressed'
              },
                backButton: {
                    image: 'back',
                    imagePressed: 'back_pressed',
                    align: 'left',
                    event: 'backPressed'
              },
                forwardButton: {
                    image: 'forward',
                    imagePressed: 'forward_pressed',
                    align: 'left',
                    event: 'forwardPressed'
              },
                closeButton: {
                    image: 'close',
                    imagePressed: 'close_pressed',
                    align: 'left',
                    event: 'closePressed'
              },
                menu: {
                    image: 'menu',
                    imagePressed: 'menu_pressed',
                    title: 'Select for quick menu',
                    cancel: 'Cancel',
                    align: 'right',
                    items: [
                             {
                               event: 'btn1Pressed',
                               label: 'Button1'
                             },
                             {
                               event: 'btn2Pressed',
                               label: 'Button2'
                             }]
                 };
               }

    function openpdf() {


// dont know how to call my pdf url....not able to get the correct code...
}


    });
```

I have few doubts.

Does my `$themeablebrowser` is corrrect that i have defined in `app.controller`.

don't know how to code inside my `click` method to open my pdf in  `Themeable url`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you have to add urls like this

```
 $scope.openpdf= function(){
    cordova.ThemeableBrowser.open('here goes your url', '_blank', {...}
 }
```

sample here

```
 $scope.openpdf= function(){
    cordova.ThemeableBrowser.open(' http://www.pdf995.com/samples/pdf.pdf', '_blank', {
        statusbar: {
            color: '#ffffffff'
        },
        toolbar: {
            height: 44,
            color: '#f0f0f0ff'
        },
        title: {
            color: '#003264ff',
            showPageTitle: true
        },
        backButton: {
            image: 'back',
            imagePressed: 'back_pressed',
            align: 'left',
            event: 'backPressed'
        },
        forwardButton: {
            image: 'forward',
            imagePressed: 'forward_pressed',
            align: 'left',
            event: 'forwardPressed'
        },
        closeButton: {
            image: 'close',
            imagePressed: 'close_pressed',
            align: 'left',
            event: 'closePressed'
        },
        customButtons: [
            {
                image: 'share',
                imagePressed: 'share_pressed',
                align: 'right',
                event: 'sharePressed'
            }
        ],
        menu: {
            image: 'menu',
            imagePressed: 'menu_pressed',
            title: 'Test',
            cancel: 'Cancel',
            align: 'right',
            items: [
                {
                    event: 'helloPressed',
                    label: 'Hello World!'
                },
                {
                    event: 'testPressed',
                    label: 'Test!'
                }
            ]
        },
        backButtonCanClose: true
    }).addEventListener('backPressed', function(e) {
        alert('back pressed');
    }).addEventListener('helloPressed', function(e) {
        alert('hello pressed');
    }).addEventListener('sharePressed', function(e) {
        alert(e.url);
    }).addEventListener(cordova.ThemeableBrowser.EVT_ERR, function(e) {
        console.error(e.message);
    }).addEventListener(cordova.ThemeableBrowser.EVT_WRN, function(e) {
        console.log(e.message);
    });
    }
```

Comment: @Ediosn.. thansk for ur solution will work out and let u know....and i have one question.. in my `app.controller('FileOpenerController', function($scope, $ionicPlatform,$themeablebrowser)`   does the defined `themeablebrowser` is correct ??

Comment: Or should i need to change some thing or what ??

Comment: @Esidon... you ter ??.. is that the defined `themeablebrowser` is correct in `app.controller('FileOpenerController', function($scope, $ionicPlatform,$themeablebrowser)`

Comment: inject `themeablebrowser`

Comment: i did but getting error in browser `Unknown provider: themeablebrowserProvider <- themeablebrowser <- LoginCtrl`

Comment: And not able to open pdf in device too

Comment: even i tried `themeablebrowser` and `$themeablebrowser`, Themeablebrowser , `$Themeablebrowser`.. BUT I AM GETTING SAME EROR

Comment: inject `themeableBrowser`  to ` angular.module('ionicApp', ['ionic','themeableBrowser'])`

Comment: I tried, but getting more error ` Failed to instantiate module themeableBrowser due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'themeableBrowser' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/nomod?p0=themeableBrowser`

Comment: here my code `angular.module('CRM.controllers', ['ionic', 'ngSanitize','themeableBrowser'])
`

Comment: any solution please.. shall i share my project demo zip ??

Comment: did you try without injecting it..?

Comment: without INJECTING ITS  SHOWS,... cordova was undefined.. adn i try to do in android device... but the button click not working...nothing changes

Comment: i tried, with cordova. But when i open i mobile. one white screen is  shows up. no pdf is showing in my browser. now what shall i do ?